# string match sequence array

Tags: java, string, loops, if-statement, char

```
public class sequence {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        char[] c = {'a','x','c','e'};
        char[] t = {'x','b'};
        int count = 0,j;

        for(int i=0;i<(c.length);i++)
        {
            int p = i;
            int x = 0;
            for( j=0;j<(t.length);j++){
                if(c[p]!=c[j]){
                    break;
                }
                else
                x++;

                System.out.print(x);
                if(x==((t.length))){
                    count++;
                }
                p++;
            }
            System.out.print('a');

        }


        System.out.println("Number of Occurences " + count);
    }

}
```

My task is to count the number of time the sequence ie t[] occurs in the mother array c[].
I am not able to get the required result even though i tries all the iterations in my mind where it worked well.I am kind of a starter in programming so need some help here.
Thankya!

Comment: the System.out statements in between  the code are just for debugginn purposes

Comment: You say "number of times the sequence occurs", do you mean only when the sequence 'x','b' is in order in `c`, or do you mean when any member of the array `t` occurs in `c`?

Comment: when both the member of t occur in c in the same sequence the appear in t

Comment: Thanks for posting the same question twice within 30 minutes. We really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

You should take this piece of code:

```
if(x==((t.length))){
    count++;
}
```

From the inner loop.

Comment: but the same piece of code will increment my count variable when there are multiple sequences of t in my mother array...as in when i increase the size of both,

Comment: such as c = {a,b,x,v,b,n,m,g,a,b,n); and t = {a,b}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `x == t.length` check is inside your inner `for` loop, but your inner `for` loop will never let `x` reach `t.length`. Also, your `x` variable is redundant and is always equal to `j` so it can be removed.

To fix this, move your length-check to the outside of the loop.

**Edit:** Also, you're accessing the wrong array in your inner loop (where the `break` statement is).

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    char[] c = {'a','x','c','e'};
    char[] t = {'x','b'};
    int count = 0, j;

    for (int i = 0; i < (c.length); i++) {
        int p = i;
        for (j = 0; j < (t.length); j++){
            if (c[p] != t[j]) {
                break;
            }
            p++;
        }
        if (j == t.length){
            count++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Number of Occurences " + count);
}
```

Comment: but you see with this i am getting wrong results. i will get count as 1 but it should logically be zero because the members of t do not occur in c in the same sequence they appear in t and moreover one of the members is missing

Comment: @user1669214 My code as posted is working. If I run it as is, I get 0, and if I run it with `t = {'x','c'}` I get 1. **Edit:** putting `'x','c'` at the end of `c` gives me 2 with `t = {'x','c'}` as well, so this is also working.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need two for loops:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    char[] c = {'a','x','b','c','x','b','e'};
    char[] t = {'x','b'};
    int count = 0;

    int tInd = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<(c.length);i++)
    {
        if(tInd < t.length && t[tInd] == c[i]){ // Found a member of t[]
            tInd ++;
        } else {
            tInd = 0; // Didn't find t[]
        }
        if(tInd == t.length){ // Found full t[] sequence
            count++;
            tInd = 0;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Number of Occurences " + count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop on all `c` elem (you can stop in the position of last possible match). In the inner loop as soon as you find a match you must continue on next `c` elem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] c = {'c','a','x','b'};
        char[] t = {'x','b'};
        int count = 0, j;

        for(int i=0;i<=(c.length-t.length);i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<(t.length);j++){
                if(t[j]!=c[i+j]){
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(j==t.length)
                count++;    
        }
        System.out.println("Number of Occurences " + count);

    }
```